# How to disallow users from adding SSL certificate exceptions in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I am looking for a way to block users from adding any SSL-error related certificate exception when they are surfing the web using Firefox (I am ultimately also interested for others browsers...).

The goal is, as an administrator, to enforce a security policy among staff users in a company context.

Example: Users could be targeted by a MITM attack to gain access to some company stuff/credentials/etc.

I thought this could be set via internal configuration but it seems not: is there any way?